How to catch and handle parameter binding errors in Python Flask application?
When an error occurs in the Flask application you can normally handle it either using try / except or by registering an application error handler (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/errorhandling/).
However if an error occurs due to invalid URL parameter Flask simply returns 500 result with an HTML page.
For example I have the following endpoint:
@app.route("/user/<login>", methods=["GET"])
Calling this route with http://localhost/users/admin will work correctly.
However if I call it like this: http://localhost/users/1 then I will get a 500 error with HTML page with HTML page title 'TypeError: The view function for xxxx. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement. did not return a valid response'
There does not seem to be any way to catch this error and handle it in some way. The function is not even entered so I can not do a try / except block.

If you register an error handler for InternalServerError then this will catch all otherwise unhandled errors when running in production (it is not activated in debug mode to allow debugging to take place unhindered).
from werkzeug.exceptions import InternalServerError   

@app.errorhandler(InternalServerError)
def handle_exception(e):
    error = e.original_exception
    return "something meaningful here"


My current error handler is setup to catch all exceptions: @app.errorhandler(Exception). InternalServerError inherits from HttpException which inherits from Exception. It works (even in debug mode) for other types of errors but not for this one.

Never mind,
my mistake, I was not returning any response in case the user was not there.
Still it is strange that this kind of error can not be handled.
